# How to AND multiple setQuery in elasticsearch using java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I am trying to create query for search filter using elasticsearch. I created query that shows results based on search term, price range and brand list. Results shown for searchterm and price range is right but when brand list is provided all results  related to selected brand is shown.

I want results for searchterm AND price AND brands

This is my query

```
BoolQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
for (String key : brands) {
    query.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("brand", key));
}

SearchResponse searchresponse = client
        .prepareSearch("product")
        .setTypes("product")
        .setQuery(
                QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("name", pSearchTerm))
        .setPostFilter(
                QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("unit_price").from(min)
                        .to(max))
        .setQuery(query).setExplain(true)
        .execute().actionGet();
```

what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two `setQuery()` calls so the second one is overriding the first one. You need to combine all your constraints into one query like this:

```
// brand list
BoolQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
for (String key : brands) {
    query.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("brand", key));
}

// search term
query.must(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("name", pSearchTerm));

// price range
query.filter(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("unit_price").from(min).to(max));

SearchResponse searchresponse = client
    .prepareSearch("product")
    .setTypes("product")
    .setQuery(query)
    .setExplain(true)
    .execute().actionGet();
```

Comment: Thats good explanation @Val. I prefer setting the filters first though. Any thoughts on the order of these statements?

Comment: It makes no difference, ES will make sure to filter the document set first and then run all matches present in your must constraints. If it helps you visually, you can move the filter() call just below the boolQuery() call.